# Is this a proper implementation of a DeleteList function? [LINKED LIST via heaps]

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I must write a function DeleteList() that takes a list, deallocates all of its memory and sets its head pointer to NULL (the empty list).

It seems to work, but idk if it truly works because the way in which I implemented (which I assume is the wrong way) is very different than the one in the solution. I assume it only deletes a few nodes or there is an issue with the memory management.

```
int Length(struct node* head)
{
    int count = 0;
    struct node* current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return(count);
}

void DeleteList(struct node** headRef)
{
    int len = Length(*headRef);
    for(int i = 0;i<len;i++)
        free(*headRef);
    *headRef = NULL;
}
```

Comment: No, it is not. You free the same pointer `Len` times.

Comment: That is what I figured - I am so stupid. I felt like I was doing that.

Answer (score 3):

You are not actually freeing the whole linked list but you are freeing head node repeatedly.  I would suggest you to use below approach.

```
void DeleteList(struct node** headRef) { 
    struct node *ptr = *headRef;
    struct node *temp = NULL;

    while(ptr)
    {
          temp = ptr;
          ptr = ptr->next;
          free(temp);
    }

    *headRef = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, added @FiddlingBits